# how can i use asp.textbox to filter a list by default(when page loads)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part

I would like to filter a DWP using parameters.
So i decided to use a asp:textbox and then filter using Control
like so:

```
<ParameterBinding Name="loc" Location="Control(locid)" DefaultValue=""/>
```

Which i think it was a good idea.I can see the control id in the list when i adding parameters.
But when i try to use it in the filter its doesn't work.
It seems the parameter is not reaching the filtering part. I actually did add the params like this also

```
<xsl:for-each select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Location = $loc]">
```

But no luck.I read somewhere that it cousl be forms but the **asp:TextBox** 
is not in a webpart.
Where should i place the as:textboz for this to work?
Also tried Forms(locid) but no luck.
Seems SP Designer 2010 is more difficult than SP 2007 Designer really

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using webpart connections. Dataview webpart can consume values from Providers which implement *IWebPartField, IWebPartRow*.

One such webpart available out-of-box is HTML Form webpart which you can connect to Dataview (Modify Webpart>Connections>Provide Form Values to). It is a textbox which you can use to filter dataview.

If you want to have your own custom provider control(Textbox), this post may help you: http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2009/08/14/exposing-sharepoint-webpart-properties-to-end-users-using-connections/

Comment: Thanks.But I did use another method using the Form Action.
Will post it soon>

Comment: define "soon" ... :)